# integration of a function $\int$ $x^2$/($x^2$+$R^2$)$^{3/2}$dx.

Tags: integration

the function is $\int$ $x^2$/($x^2$+$R^2$)$^{3/2}$dx. 
I substituted x=Rtan$\theta$ and got $\int$cos$\theta$tan$^2$$\theta$d$\theta$. And here i am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta-1$ to write that as$$\int(\sec\theta-\cos\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta=\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|-\sin\theta+C.$$